# Dart IO process.run('pbcopy', []) - How to use?

Tags: dart

I am a beginner and I have a problem. I would like to use dart:io process with the command "pbcopy". I tried this but it seems that it doesn't work :

```
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  Process.run('echo', ['hello', '|', 'pbcopy']);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`echo` is an internal command from your shell and `|` is also a shell-only feature, not a command parameter.
If you're on Linux or Mac, you can try

```
Process.run('bash', ['-c', 'echo hello | pbcopy']);
```

Comment: Great, glad to hear :)